# How to get rid of the special characters getting from the database using smarty?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

Some of my contents which are coming directly from MySQL database are displayed like  `â€™` , `â€”` characters.

I guess while inserting the data into the database, I mistakenly used **`SET NAMES utf-8`** instead of **`SET NAMES utf8`**. For which the special characters are not converted properly and showing as it is.

In order to avoid these I used the follwoing in the page between `<head>` tag ..
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html";charset=UTF-8" />` .

But it didn't work.

How to convert these into its original characters while showing in the page ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function charConversion($string, $to = "HTML-ENTITIES", $from = 'UTF-8,ASCII,ISO-8859-9,ISO-8859-1') {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($string, $to, $from);
    $str = stripslashes($str);
    if (empty($str)) {
        return $string;
    }
    return $str;
}
```